TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in dictionary key value
a = input("enter the message")
a = list(a)
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
     "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
     ",", ".", "?", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*",
     "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
d = {}
for i in a:
    c = 0
    for j in b:
        if i == j:
            
            d[j] = c # Use dictionary assignment instead of update
            
        c = c + 1
print(d)
e = ""
for i in d.keys():
    print(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        
        c = int(i / 2)
        f = 0
        for j in b:
            if c == f:
                e = e + j
        
    else:
        c = int((i - 1) / 2)
        f = 0
        for j in b:
            if c == f:
                e = e + j
print(e)

I don't know how to fix it. I am new to the programming and i don't have much idea.
please help me how to fix it.
I know that in dictionary keys are integer but still it give the error.
it give TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I know that in dictionary keys are integer this assumption is wrong, the keys are strings.

Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Ok so what is right please tell me. i don't know as i am beginner.

'Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mani/Desktop/mani-demo-new/100dayschellenge/projects/secretcodelangugesend.py", line 21, in 
if i % 2 == 0:
~~^~~
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

We can't tell you how to solve this since we have no idea what you are trying to do. I can tell you that the keys can never be integers because you are taking them from a list with non-numeric values (list b).

i just want to make an secret message program which take msg and convert it into secret msg. then at the end of receiver we just reverse whole processes. so that he get the real msg.

If s is a string that represents an integer, int(s) returns this integer.

It would help without single letter var names. What's j? e? b?

thanks everyone i just understand the error and find right way.

am guessing you are trying to build a simple encryption/decryption algorithm.
I am using ascii values of characters as keys to make it more convenient.
In the second loop, you're trying to iterate over keys of the dictionary d, which are characters. Then you're trying to perform arithmetic operations (% 2, / 2) directly on these characters. This won't work as expected
This is a modified code and it should work fine
a = input("Enter the message: ")
a = list(a)
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
     "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
     ",", ".", "?", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*",
     "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

d = {}
for i in a:
    for j, char in enumerate(b):
        if i == char:
            d[i] = j

print("Encrypted Dictionary:", d)

e = ""
for i in d.keys():
    index = d[i]
    if index % 2 == 0:
        c = int(index / 2)
    else:
        c = int((index - 1) / 2)
    e += b[c]

print("Decrypted message:", e)

